# How to get previous and next data

Tags: php, angular

My api data list

```
{
  "data" : [
   {
     "id": 201,
     "content": "something"
   },
   {
     "id": 202,
     "content": "something"
   },
   {
     "id": 204,
     "content": "something"
   },
   {
     "id": 206,
     "content": "something"
   }
  ]
}
```

I want to get item with previous and next data example :

I enter some article and have a previous and next button for previous and next article.

Can it solve with fontend (angular) or it have to slove with backend (laravel).

Live example :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12c2np
(next and previous button at post.component)

What I have tried.

Query all posts data and use index as param to fetch single post. This method cannot use with social sharing because when user add new post, the index key is same but it data has change to new post example : old /1 param has title "old title" when user add new post the /1 param will be "new title"

What I think but dont know what to do.

Query current data with exact data id.
Query previous data with data id < current data id.
Query next data with data id > current data id.

OR

Modify backend to query 3 data that contain current, previous and next data.

Is there a better way to do it.

Comment: if data is big use backend otherwise frontend is ok. just try yourself first we are here to help you.

Comment: if you need to store data temporary, u can save it in some service. If you can create a demo on stackblitz.com then I'll try to show u in it

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12c2np.
previous and next post at post.component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator rxjs pairwise(). It emits previous and current value that you want